# Loop over points and label them with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following source works, as shown.

Is there a way to alter the commented out`\foreach` block of code so that it will do the same thing as the two separate lines above it?

If commented out, the `\foreach` block (as corrected) does produce the two points, but the label below the first point is wrong: it displays literally as (1/pi, 0) whereas I want it to show the result of $(1/\pi, 0)$, namely, (1/π,0).

(This is a toy example. In practice, there will be more points, hence the desire to use a looping construct.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:1,x=7cm,y=2cm]
  % axis:
  \draw[->,gray,thick] (-0.2,0) -- (1.15,0) node[right,black] {$x$};
  % points:
  \fill (1/pi, 0) circle[radius=2pt] node[below] {$(1/\pi, 0)$};
  \fill (1, 0) circle[radius=2pt] node[below] {$(1, 0)$};
% The following does NOT work!
%  \foreach \Point in {(1/pi,0), (1,0)} {
%   \fill \Point circle[radius=2pt] node[below] {$\Point$};
%   };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: How use looping instead of separate statements for each point here]

Comment: Just look at the error message: "! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?." If you add a semicolon there it works.

Comment: @dexteritas: Sorry for the typo that omitted the semicolon. That wasn't my issue; i've added more explicity what the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest just adjusting the `\foreach` loop with a second variable where'd you specify the tet to be typeset. If the second variable is not specified in the list the previous variable will be used instead.

This allows you to do

```
\foreach \Point/\Label in {{(1/pi, 0)}/{(1/\pi, 0)}, (1, 0)}
  \fill \Point circle[radius=2pt] node[below] {$\Label$};
```

and both `\Point` and `\Label` will be `(1, 0)` in the second iteration.

---

However, you can use LaTeX3's `l3regex` package to replace text like `pi` with the control sequence `\pi`.
If it's just `pi`/`\pi` this should do but with complexer examples it won't be that easy. The second entry should really read 11° and not just 11, shouldn't it?

The `xstring` package has `\StrSubstitute` but using it with more than one replacement will be more tedious.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\tikzmathreplacer}{m}{
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_case_all:nN {
    { pi  }{ \c{pi}  }
    { sin }{ \c{sin} }
    { *   }{         }
  } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:1,x=7cm,y=2cm]
\draw[->,gray,thick] (-0.2,0) -- (1.15,0) node[right,black] {$x$};
\foreach \Point/\Label in {{(1/pi, 0)}/{(1/\pi, 0)}, (1, 0)}
  \fill \Point circle[radius=2pt] node[below] {$\Label$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:1,x=7cm,y=2cm]
\draw[->,gray,thick] (-0.2,0) -- (1.15,0) node[right,black] {$x$};
\foreach \Point in {(1/pi, 0), ({pi * sin(11)}, 0), (1, 0)}
  \fill \Point circle[radius=2pt] node[below] {$\tikzmathreplacer{\Point}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]