# Printing a value in math print from command input

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

I am trying to create a new command with 2 inputs: radius and radian. I got everything to work with the command but when I compile the radian value prints out as 2*pi/4 (for example) instead of the actual 2 pi symbol divide by 4. Is there a way around that? Here is the code for the new command; #1 = radius and #2=radian

```
\newcommand{\arcR}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, font=\sffamily\Large,scale=0.5]
    \draw (0,0) circle[radius=5];
    \draw[very thick,fill=blue!30] 
        (0,0) -- ({deg(#2)}:5) 
        arc[start angle={deg(#2)}, end angle=0, radius=5] -- cycle;
    \draw[latex-latex] 
        ({deg(#2)}:1.2) 
        arc[start angle={deg(#2)}, end angle=0, radius=1.2] 
        node[above=5pt, midway] {$#2$};
    \draw[very thick,-latex] (0,0) -- (0:5) 
        node[midway,below=2pt]{$#1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\arcR{5}{2*pi/3}
```

will produce the following image:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my answer to [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/685896/47927) so that it now contains a solution for this problem as well. But maybe someone else has a better idea even.

Comment: Related: [Q678916](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/678916)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering @Qrrbrbirlbel comment, and libraries `angles` and `quotes`:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,
                quotes}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\symbreplace}{m}{
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_case_all:nN {
    { pi  }{ \c{pi}  }
    { *   }{         }
  } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand\arcRQ[2]{
\draw   (0,0) circle[radius=5];
\path[draw=blue, fill=blue!50, very thick, semitransparent]
        (0,0) coordinate (c) -- (0:5) coordinate (a)
                             arc (0:deg(#1):#2cm) coordinate (b)
                             -- cycle;
\pic [ANG, "$\symbreplace{#1}$"]  {angle = a--c--b};
              }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         > = Straight Barb,
ANG/.style = {draw, semithick, <->,
              angle radius = 12mm,
              angle eccentricity=1.3,
              font=\Large\sffamily}
                    ]
%%%%
\arcRQ{2*pi/3}{5}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thanks a lot. But is there a way to run the new command in the main of the  document? I wanted to add the new command in the preamble and then use it whenever I wanted to add a new arc length problem in the assignment.

Comment: @Yahya, it also works if you you move `\newcommand` definition to preamble. See edited answer.

Comment: Great. That worked!! This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Yahya, Your thankfulness you should express by upvoting of answer (by clicking on up triangle at left top side od answer),  according to policy of this site. Also now is time that you decide which of received answer solve your problem on the best way and than accept them )click on check mark below triangles). By this you will inform audience here, that your question is solved. As I see, so far you not accept any of answers received on your questions.

Comment: Done. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

You could parse the number using the `l3regex` package, maybe (but I am unsure whether this is the most optimal solution here since this will only work for a specific syntax as noted in the comments in the code below):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% transforms any number of the form x, x*pi, pi/x or x*pi/y 
% into properly styled math-mode
% where x and y can be any number, with or without decimal separator (dot)
\seq_new:N \l_topifrac_temp_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\topifrac}{ m }{
    \regex_extract_once:nnN { \A(\d*\.?\d+)?(\*?pi)?(/(\d*\.?\d+))?\Z } 
        { #1 } \l_topifrac_temp_seq
    \seq_item:Nn \l_topifrac_temp_seq { 2 }
    \tl_if_blank:eTF { \seq_item:Nn \l_topifrac_temp_seq { 5 } } 
        { \tl_if_blank:eTF { \seq_item:Nn \l_topifrac_temp_seq { 3 } }  
            { }
            { \pi }
        }
        { \frac{\pi}{ \seq_item:Nn \l_topifrac_temp_seq { 5 } } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\arcR}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick, font=\sffamily\Large, scale=0.5]
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=5];
        \draw[very thick, fill=blue!30] 
            (0,0) -- ({deg(#2)}:5) 
            arc[start angle={deg(#2)}, end angle=0, radius=5] -- cycle;
        \draw[latex-latex] 
            ({deg(#2)}:1.2) 
            arc[start angle={deg(#2)}, end angle=0, radius=1.2] 
            node[above=5pt, midway] {$\topifrac{#2}$};
        \draw[very thick, -latex] (0,0) -- (0:5) 
            node[midway, below=2pt]{$#1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\arcR{5}{2*pi/3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use `\arcR{5}{2\pi/3}` in te input and then when you need to do computation, you could replace the `\pi` with `*pi`.

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\arcR}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, font=\sffamily\Large,scale=0.5]
    \StrSubstitute{#2}{\pi}{*pi}[\RadianMeasure]% Replace '\pi' with '*pi'
    \pgfmathsetmacro\DegreeMeasure{deg(\RadianMeasure)}%
    %% -------------
    \draw (0,0) circle[radius=5];
    \draw[very thick,fill=blue!30] 
        (0,0) -- ({\DegreeMeasure}:5) 
        arc[start angle={\DegreeMeasure}, end angle=0, radius=5] -- cycle;
    \draw[latex-latex] 
        ({\DegreeMeasure}:1.2) 
        arc[start angle={\DegreeMeasure}, end angle=0, radius=1.2] 
        node[above=5pt, midway] {$#2$};
    \draw[very thick,-latex] (0,0) -- (0:5) 
        node[midway,below=2pt]{$#1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
  \arcR{5}{2\pi/3}
\end{document}
```